# After ASPX page file rename "The name 'message' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I know there hundreds of questions out there that are similar to this one, but in this case the code is/was correct and compiles.

**Renaming the page file(s) causes the problem.**

I attempted a rename in Visual Studio. There is a message after attempting the rename.

[image]

Afterwards, every UI element in the `aspx` file is not available to the `aspx.cs` file. Everything looks OK, except the Intellisense doesn't recognise any UI element, and it won't compile. The `aspx`, `aspx.cs`, and `designer.cs` files have been properly renamed.

I have tried everything; clean build, inspecting the project file, updating Visual Studio, restarting Visual Studio, deleting the `obj` folder, restarting Windows, changing the class name, deleting and rebuilding the designer file, creating a new page and copying the code, fiddling with the `CodeBehind` and `Inherits` properties in the `Page` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I was able to get the thing to compile *again*, by:

- create a new page with the desired name
- compile
- copy the `aspx` code
- recompile
- copy the `cs` code
- recompile
- change class name
- recompile

I also needed to add a `using` to the `cs` file which is the same as the `namespace` of the class which seems a little weird. This was because there is a custom UI element in the same namespace. But as I said this had previously compiled.

Hope this helps someone...

`Edit`

Turns out the problem was caused by an uppercase character in the namespace that needed to be lowercase. Very confusing that it *sometimes* compiled...

`Edit`

To clarify, what happened was a page was added to a project and the namespace for the corresponding class had a (camel) uppercase character that should have been lowercase to match the other classes. Thus the namespace for the new page, (code behind) class, and designer file matched (exactly). However, the namespace didn't match the namespace for the rest of the project and thus caused this headache!

Comment: When you did the rename, did you also change the namespace in the codebehind?   That might have been the problem.

Comment: Ah. It turns out that the problem was a case mismatch in the namespace. (Hangs head in shame...) I guess I was confused by the fact that it did compile, then became broken without me changing anything.